# how to monitor and earlier stop a training with tf.estimator.Estimator based on evaluation on validation dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, monitor

validation_monitor is decapitated, how can we monitor and earlier stop an estimator's training based on evaluation based on a validation set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ValidationMonitor is deprecated -- it can lead to subtle failures. There is no hook to replace it.

To locally train and repeatedly evaluate a model, make an Experiment, and call train_and_evaluate.

See: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/-aR9pZoFntI

Comment: This answer is deprecated because the [Experiment class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) is also deprecated.